# Combine two js functions to show/hide toggle

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, getelementbyid

I'm currently using two functions to show and hide elements on a project I'm working on.

One function is for when the element is currently `.display = 'block'` and the other is for when the element is currently `.display = 'none'`.

```
function hide1(id) {
    ele = document.getElementById(id);
if (ele.style.display == 'block')
    ele.style.display = 'none';
else
    ele.style.display = 'block'; }

function hide2(id) {
    ele = document.getElementById(id);
if (ele.style.display == 'none')
    ele.style.display = 'block';
else
    ele.style.display = 'none'; }
```

I'm all for optimization and am wondering if there is a way to combine both functions into one, or if its fine to keep them as they are.

Cheers,

Comment: Both of your functions (hide1 and hide2) do the same thing already; toggle the element with id = id.

Comment: Essentially they do, but one function will require two clicks (onclick event) and the other just one. http://jsfiddle.net/Yhs6y/

Comment: Each of the two functions does the same thing after being called just once:  if the element is hidden, show it, if the element is shown, hide it.  You are just checking the property differently and have your ifs in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hide(id) {
    ele = document.getElementById(id);
    ele.style.display = (ele.style.display == 'block')?'none':'block';
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining this? It looks like it would do the same as my original `function hide1`, unless that's all I needed. This shorthand is all new to me :)

Comment: It combines both your functions. If element is displayed it changes `style.display` to `'none'` and vice versa. Short form replaces 4 your lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ChangeDisplay(id,prevDisplay,newDisplay) {
ele = document.getElementById(id);
if (ele.style.display == prevDisplay)
ele.style.display = newDisplay; 
else
ele.style.display == prevDisplay;
}
```

That should do your work